# How Insert data from SparkR to Hbase in hadoop cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, sparkr

I am looking for help with getting SparkR data to be directly loaded into HBase.
The read function is working where I am able to read data from Hive external tables using SparkR (sparkR.session)

Steps performed:

- Created an HBase table (hbase_test1)
- Created an external table in Hive to map HBase table in Hive (test1)

Code:

```
library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.session(master = "local",sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="2g",enableHiveSupport=TRUE))
sqlContext <- sparkR.session(sc)

df <- sql("show tables")
collect(df)

sdf <- sql("SELECT * from test1")
```

This is where I stand.

Can I write the data directly to HBase directly from SparkR?
FYI: I need to use SparkR for certain ML code. The results need to be saved back into HBase. Please Note I am using all open source tools.

Answer (score 0):

With no additional deployment you can use  [Apache Spark - Apache HBase Connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc).

First you have to include the package. It can be done with the following options*

```
spark.jars.packages  com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11
spark.jars.repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/
```

in your `spark-defaults.conf` or equivalent command line arguments for `spark-submit` / `SparkR`

```
--packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 \
--repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/
```

The version (`s_2.11` above) of the package has to match Scala version used to build Spark.

Now let's say you defined your table as

```
create 'FooBar', 'Foo', 'Bar'
```

and you want SparkR insert equivalent to:

```
put 'FooBar', '1000', 'Foo:Value', 'x1'
put 'FooBar', '1000', 'Bar:Value', 'y1'
put 'FooBar', '2000', 'Foo:Value', 'x2'
put 'FooBar', '2000', 'Bar:Value', 'y2'
```

You have to provide a catalog mapping:

```
catalog = '{
  "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"FooBar"},
  "rowkey":"key",
  "columns":{
  "rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
  "foo_value":{"cf":"Foo", "col":"Value", "type":"string"},
  "bar_value":{"cf":"Bar", "col":"Value", "type":"string"}
  }
}'
```

and the input table:

```
df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(
  rowkey = c("1000", "2000"), foo_value = c("x1", "x2"), bar_value = c("y1", "y2")
))
```

Finally you can apply `write.ml` with the following options:

```
write.df(df, 
   source = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase", 
   mode = "append", catalog = catalog)
```

Please refer to the [official connector documantion](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) for details.

If you don't mind additional dependencies, you can deploy [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/index.html), map your HBase tables (check for example [PHOENIX-447](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-447)) and then use either [the official connector](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html) or [built-in JDBC source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), to write your data.

At additional cost it will provide much better user experience. For example if you defined Phoenix table as:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
  id VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  foo INTEGER, 
  bar VARCHAR
);
```

you could

```
SparkR:::callJStatic(
  "java.lang.Class", "forName",  
  "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver"
)


df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(
  id = c("1000", "2000"), foo = c(1, 2), bar = c("x", "y")
))


write.df(
  dfr, source = "org.apache.phoenix.spark", 
  # Note that the only supported mode is `overwrite`, 
  # which in fact works like `UPSERT`
  mode = "overwrite",
  table = "FooBar", 
  # ZooKeeper URL
  zkUrl = "host:port"  
)
```

Similarly to the first option you'll have to include [corresponding connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark). However, unlike HBase connector, it is not self sufficient and requires Phoenix Core and Client jars on the `CLASSPATH`.

---

* Don't forget to adjust package version in the future.

Comment: I had to edit my comment, hence re-writing it.
I have tried the above-mentioned step (2nd option).
When I tried to write the content into HBase table, I am getting the error: Error: Error in save : org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.InvalidRegionNumberException: Number of regions specified for new table must be greater than 3.

Also when I tried the same using RStudio using 1st option mentioned, Nothing seems to work. Please suggest.

Comment: Please note, I want to write the content back to an existing HBase table from which I read the data and perform some mining. Using Hadoop 2.9.0, HBase version: 1.4.7 and Spark 2.3.0 pre-build for Hadoop.

Comment: Isn't the error related to https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/76 (but it would it applies to the 1st not 2nd option). And to  the second one - if you have existing Hbase table, it is not exposed to Phoenix.To be able to access it you'll have to create a matching Phoenix view, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. 
I have gone through github thread. But my concern is when iam trying to pass the argument 'HBaseTableCatalog.newTable' i get another error: 
write.df(df, source = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase", mode = "append", catalog = catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5")
Error in .local(df, path, ...) :

object 'HBaseTableCatalog.newTable' not found

Not sure if this is the right syntax in SparkR. Also, I do not have Phoenix installed. Is there any workaround to access without Phoenix?

Comment: Rather `write.df(df, source = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase", mode = "append", catalog = catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable = "5")`

Comment: I tried the code suggested but now I am facing this Error: Error in save: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.InvalidRegionNumberException: Number of regions specified for new table must be greater than 3.

Comment: Please help, I am desperate to get this thing work but nothing seems to be working in favour here.

Comment: I wish I knew why this code fails for you but I don't. Are you able to read from the same table? Does it work for a different one?

Comment: No, I tried with a different table as well (refer: https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/interacting-with-hbase-from-pyspark/). Using pyspark as well the code fails. 
 df = sqlContext.read.options(catalog=catalog).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').load()
File "/home/hduser/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.load.
: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field

Comment: This one sounds like malformed `catalog` JSON.

Comment: Ahhh wonderful....thanks for the hint. It is working now to read the data in pyspark. Checking with write option as well.
I will verify the same in SparkR and update

Comment: Read of HBase tables using Pyspark

Pyspark:
----------
pyspark --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/

cat = '{"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"FooBar"},"rowkey":"key","columns": 
{"rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},"foo_value":{"cf":"Foo", 
"col":"Value", "type":"string"},  "bar_value":{"cf":"Bar", "col":"Value", 
"type":"string"} }}'

df = sqlContext.read.options(catalog=cat).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').load()

Comment: Write to HBash tables using Pyspark:

data = sc.parallelize([('3000', 'x3', 'y3'), ('4000', 'x4', 'y4')]).toDF(schema=['rowkey', 'f1_value', 'f2_value'])

data.write.option("catalog",cat).option("newtable","5").format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()

df1 = sqlContext.read.options(catalog=cat).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').load()

Comment: Read Hbase table using SparkR:

sparkR --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/

Catalog to Map Hbase tables with dataframe
    cat = '{
      "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"FooBar"},
      "rowkey":"key",
      "columns":{
      "rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
      "foo_value":{"cf":"Foo", "col":"Value", "type":"string"},
      "bar_value":{"cf":"Bar", "col":"Value", "type":"string"}
      }
    }'

Comment: create a df in sparkR:

data1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(rowkey = c("4000", "5000"), foo_value = c("x4", "x5"), bar_value = c("y4", "y5")))


write.df(data1, source = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase", mode = "append", catalog = cat, newTable = "5")

df1 <- read.df(source = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase", catalog = cat)

collect(df1)